# Word ActiveX drop down list item selection

Tags: vba, ms-word, dropdown, activex, word-table

I have a Word table, in which I have created drop down lists with different elements. With a short macro I would like to set these drop down lists to nothing (e.g. white char), because later I would like to save the document as PDF. If I set the table cell value to "", then it is deleting also the drop down list.

Do you have any recommendation how can I do this?

Thank you very much for your support.
Best Regards,
JJ

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This was the specific problem. But never mind, I have created an element with white char as value and found a short code, which does the job: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?38257-Solved-VBA-code-to-set-Drop-Down-content-control-to-first-value

Comment: In your question you asked for help with ActiveX controls. The solution you reference is for content controls, which are entirely different.

Comment: The point was to find any solution / get recommendations. From my side your comment is accepted, thanks for the hint. Until next time